# Why is this if statement in my event handler not working on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, backbone.js, marionette, youtube-javascript-api

I have an event handler in my Backbone app that listens for when a YouTube video ends, then find the next video and plays it. It works perfectly on desktop, but not on iOS. It recognizes the event and fires the handler, but my if statement doesn't work for some reason.

```
App.Player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function(newState){
    // Play / Pause functionality
    var currentSong = App.Player.getVideoData();
    if (theVideoId == currentSong.video_id){
      if (newState.data == 1){
        $("#play-pause").addClass("playing")
      } else if (newState.data == 2){
        $("#play-pause").removeClass("playing")
      }
    };

    // When song ends, play the next song in playlist
    if (newState.data == 0){
      for (var i=0; i < App.playList.size(); i++){
        if (App.playList.models[i].get("id") == App.nowPlaying.get("id")){
          // none of this code executes on iOS, but works fine on desktop
          var nextVideo = App.playList.models[i+1];
          var promise = nextVideo.fetch();
          $.when(promise).then(function(){
            App.Player.cueVideoById(nextVideo.get("video")).playVideo();;
            App.nowPlaying = nextVideo;
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
},
```

Any idea why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Which of 'if' not work? it is hard to check javascript on iOS device. So you can add try catch block and call alert in catch to detect if there is some js errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that when the user presses play directly on the video iframe itself (which is required on iOS), I was not setting App.nowPlaying and so clearly that IF statement could never be true. I just had to make sure to set App.nowPlaying, and things are working swimmingly on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Most mobile devices will only allow playback of audio/video with direct, physical, and synchronous interaction from the user (e.g. `onclick`, `ontouchstart`, etc.). You are breaking this rule by waiting for your asynchronous `nextVideo.fetch()` promise to resolve before attempting to play the video. You should be able to resolve this by asking the user to click something to start the next video or you can try making your `nextVideo.fetch()` call synchronous.

Comment: By the time this code runs, the user has already directly clicked play and initiated playback, so it should work. What I don't understand is that inside that IF statement, even if I just try to log to console, it doesn't run on iOS.